# How to extend rule until the end of beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, rules

I want to include a rule from a logo in a beamer slide until the right margin of the slide.

However, when I increase the width of rule, the rule is sent to below the image instead of continuing toward the right margin. This happens in the MWE below when I change the rule width from 10 cm to values above 11.6 cm. I want the rule to be extended until the rigth margin of the slide. Thank you.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

{\centering {\LARGE Some text}\par}

\ \par

The first line does not extend until the right margin of the slide.

How can I extend it until the right margin?

\vskip0pt plus 1filll

\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a} \rule{11.6cm}{2.2mm}

\rule{\paperwidth}{2.2mm}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `{\LARGE Some text}\par` will result in a wrong line spacing.

Comment: Good to know. It is because of the `\LARGE`, or because I am not using itemize?

Comment: You need to use the `\par` before you switch back to normal font. Otherwise the line spacing of the normal size will be used for the large text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your image and rule into some element which spans the whole paper width and not just the text width.

Such elements could for example be a columns environment or the footline.

Example with footline:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\mbox{}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.5cm-1cm}{2.2mm}%

\vskip0.5cm
}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

{\centering {\LARGE Some text\par}}

\ \par

The first line does not extend until the right margin of the slide.

How can I extend it until the right margin?
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Example with columns:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

{\centering {\LARGE Some text\par}}

\ \par

The first line does not extend until the right margin of the slide.

How can I extend it until the right margin?

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{\paperwidth}
\mbox{}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.5cm-1cm}{2.2mm}%
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I managed to produce the desired result using `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]`  `\column{1\paperwidth}` `\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a} \rule{13.5cm}{2.2mm}` `\end{columns}`

Comment: However, I could not produce the image of your example. It only appears the very top of the example-image-a and the rule does not appear

Comment: @Andre Why do you restrict the width of the `columns` environment to only the text width when you then use a column spanning the whole paperwidth?

Comment: @Andre Is your beamer version up-to-date? This will need beamer v3.70 to get the frame geometry right. Without this the height of the footline won't be updated automatically.

Comment: With `[onlytextwidth]`, the example-image-a becomes aligned with the left of the text "The first line"

Comment: @Andre And you will get an overfull box. You can use `\mbox{}\hspace{1cm}` to align the image with the text margin.

Comment: I am using beamer v3.68

Comment: If you don't care for the overfull box, you could simply remove the space after your image. No point in using columns.

Comment: I have updated beamer to v 3.70. Your answer now compiles